# Spring Data JPA, Save with argument String[]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to use Spring-Data-JPA and Spring-boot. I have question about how to save or insert into database with Spring-Data-JPA with argument String[] arrays.
Here the Example of my table :

Table A => id|col_0|col_1|col_2|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|col_10

I have an array that I've got from parsing file (Different file - Different length of array and not bigger than Table A Col_ )

**The class of TableA :**

```
public class TableA implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "col_0")
private String col0;

@Column(name = "col_1")
private String col1;

@Column(name = "col_2")
private String col2;

@Column(name = "col_3")
private String col3;

@Column(name = "col_4")
private String col4;

@Column(name = "col_5")
private String col5;

@Column(name = "col_6")
private String col6;

@Column(name = "col_7")
private String col7;

@Column(name = "col_8")
private String col8;

@Column(name = "col_9")
private String col9;

@Column(name = "col_10")
private String col10;

/*Setter Getter*/
```

The question if how is the simplest method to save or insert Array into Table A with Spring Data JPA. 
For example I have file1 has 5 index and File2 has 8 index.

Example:

```
String[] file1 = file.split(".");
String[] result = new String[Constant.MAX_ROW_OF_TABLE_A]; //12

for (int i = 0; i < file1.length; i++){
   result[i] = file1[i];
}

tableARepository.insertIntoDatabase(result); //How the method to insert ?
```

That's all my question, I hope that I can find the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Conver result[i] into and object of entity TableA  and then do the save. You cannot do the save with result array

Comment: By not using Spring Data JPA. Create an insert query and use plain JDBC.

Comment: Thanks @ArunM I have solved my problem with your answer. Thanks all :)